# c# DataGridView DataTable internal index corrupted in parallel loop

Tags: c#, datagridview, parallel-processing

Have one hidden column with encrypted values and i want to copy and decrypt these values to another column, for speed up this process i'm using parallel for loop, but it's working only on my desktop PC, when i tried it on my notebook i get these errors:

> DataTable internal index corrupted: '5'
>
> DataTable internal index corrupted: '13'

```
public void LoadKeyStarter()
{
    DataTable dt;
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
    dt = DS.Tables[0];
    dt.Columns.Add("Decrypted", typeof(System.String));
    keystoregridview.DataSource = dt;
        
    LoadKeyColumn = new Thread(LoadKeyColumnValues);

    LoadKeyColumn.Start();
}

public void LoadKeyColumnValues()
{
     try
     {
         #NOT WORKING ON NB
         Parallel.For(0, keystoregridview.Rows.Count, i =>
         {
             keystoregridview.Rows[i].Cells["Decrypted"].Value = Decrypt(keystoregridview.Rows[i].Cells["Encrypted"].Value.ToString());
         });

         /* WORKING BOTH
         for (int i = 0; i < keystoregridview.Rows.Count; i++)
         {
             keystoregridview.Rows[i].Cells["Decrypted"].Value = Decrypt(keystoregridview.Rows[i].Cells["Encrypted"].Value.ToString());
         }*/
     }
     catch (Exception _ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(_ex.ToString());
     }
}
```

Is there any fix for it?

Comment: [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx): _This type is safe for multithreaded read operations. You must synchronize any write operations._

Comment: @TaW  I don't modify datatable while thread is running why is it getting corrupted?

Comment: _keystoregridview.Rows[i].Cells["Decrypted"].Value =.._ How is that not a modification? (The DGV is databound after all, right?)

Comment: @TaW if it is correct why is it working on another pc without corruption?

Comment: Multithreading is hard to predict; different cores, workload etc..