# Guid.NewGuid() is returning duplicate values when used in a Parallel.For loop

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, guid, sqlbulkcopy

I have an application that is hitting an API.  As such, it does a query for all ID's in the object, and then has to query each item one at a time per ID.  I'm doing this in a Parallel.For loop and adding each items data to a row in a datatable.  Then I use sqlbulkcopy to send the datatable to a SQL server table.

If I do this without using Parallel.For, it works great.  However, with Parallel.For, this line:

```
workrow["id"] = Guid.NewGuid();
```

is generating duplicate Guids.  It's doing it often and causing the data to not load into the SQL server table because the id row in SQL is a Primary Key and doesn't allow duplicates.  I tried locking:

```
                    lock (lockobject)
                    {
                        workrow["id"] = Guid.NewGuid();
                    }
```

This didn't help.
I tried not assigning an id to that field in hopes that SQL would generate it (it does have newid() on that field).  That fails saying it can't insert a null.
I can't seem to just remove the id field from the datatable because then the columns don't align when I do the sqlbulkcopy.

Can someone help me here?  I either need to figure out how to get Guid.NewGuid() to STOP producing duplicates OR I need to figure out a way to not pass in the id (always the first field in the datatable) so that SQL will generate the id.

Here is the code I use to generate one of tables:

```
        public static DataTable MakeWorkflowTable()
        {
            DataTable Workflow = new DataTable("Workflow");
            DataColumn id = new DataColumn("id", System.Type.GetType("System.Guid"));
            Workflow.Columns.Add(id);
            DataColumn OrgInfoID = new DataColumn("OrgInfoID", System.Type.GetType("System.Guid"));
            Workflow.Columns.Add(OrgInfoID);
            DataColumn Name = new DataColumn("Name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
            Workflow.Columns.Add(Name);
            DataColumn Active = new DataColumn("Active", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
            Workflow.Columns.Add(Active);
            DataColumn Description = new DataColumn("Description", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
            Workflow.Columns.Add(Description);
            DataColumn Object = new DataColumn("Object", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
            Workflow.Columns.Add(Object);
            DataColumn Formula = new DataColumn("Formula", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
            Workflow.Columns.Add(Formula);
            DataColumn ManageableState = new DataColumn("ManageableState", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
            Workflow.Columns.Add(ManageableState);
            DataColumn NameSpacePrefix = new DataColumn("NameSpacePrefix", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
            Workflow.Columns.Add(NameSpacePrefix);
            DataColumn TDACount = new DataColumn("TDACount", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
            Workflow.Columns.Add(TDACount);
            DataColumn TriggerType = new DataColumn("TriggerType", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
            Workflow.Columns.Add(TriggerType);
            DataColumn CreatedDate = new DataColumn("CreatedDate", System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));
            Workflow.Columns.Add(CreatedDate);
            DataColumn CreatedBy = new DataColumn("CreatedBy", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
            Workflow.Columns.Add(CreatedBy);
            DataColumn LastModifiedDate = new DataColumn("LastModifiedDate", System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));
            Workflow.Columns.Add(LastModifiedDate);
            DataColumn LastModifiedBy = new DataColumn("LastModifiedBy", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
            Workflow.Columns.Add(LastModifiedBy);
            return Workflow;
        }
```

Here is the code I use to send it to the SQL server:

```
        public static void SendDTtoDB(ref DataTable dt, ref SqlConnection cnn, string TableName)
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(cnn))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName =
                    TableName;
                try
                {
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                    dt.Clear();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    logger.Warn("SendDTtoDB {TableName}: ORGID: {ORGID} : {Message}", TableName, dt.Rows[0]["OrgInfoID"], e.Message.ToString());
                    if (e.Message.ToString().Contains("PRIMARY KEY"))
                    {
                        foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            logger.Warn("ID: {id}", row["id"]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

As you can see in the catch statement, I set it to write out the ID's to the log so I could see them for myself and, sure enough, there is a duplicate there.  So frustrating!  I really don't want to take out the Parallel.For and single thread it if I don't have to.

Per request, here is the code with the Parallel.For

```
              if (qr.totalSize > 0)
                {
                    object lockobject = new object();
                    Parallel.For(0, qr.records.Length, i =>
                    {
                        ToolingService.CustomTab1 vr = new ToolingService.CustomTab1();

                        vr = (ToolingService.CustomTab1)qr.records[i];
                        string mdSOQL = "Select FullName, description, ManageableState, MasterLabel, NamespacePrefix, Type, Url, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name, "
                            + "LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedBy.Name From CustomTab where id='" + vr.Id + "'";
                        ToolingService.QueryResult mdqr = new ToolingService.QueryResult();
                        ToolingService.CustomTab1 vrmd = new ToolingService.CustomTab1();
                        mdqr = ts.query(mdSOQL);
                        vrmd = (ToolingService.CustomTab1)mdqr.records[0];

                        DataRow workrow = CustomTabs.NewRow();
                        lock (lockobject)
                        {
                            workrow["id"] = Guid.NewGuid();
                        }
                        workrow["OrgInfoID"] = _orgDBID;
                        workrow["FullName"] = vrmd.FullName;
                        workrow["Description"] = vrmd.Description ?? Convert.DBNull;
                        workrow["ManageableState"] = vrmd.ManageableState;
                        workrow["MasterLabel"] = vrmd.MasterLabel ?? Convert.DBNull;
                        workrow["NameSpacePrefix"] = vrmd.NamespacePrefix ?? Convert.DBNull;
                        workrow["Type"] = vrmd.Type ?? Convert.DBNull;
                        workrow["URL"] = vrmd.Url ?? Convert.DBNull;
                        workrow["CreatedDate"] = vrmd.CreatedDate ?? Convert.DBNull;
                        if (vrmd.CreatedBy == null)
                        {
                            workrow["CreatedBy"] = Convert.DBNull;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            workrow["CreatedBy"] = vrmd.CreatedBy.Name;
                        }
                        workrow["LastModifiedDate"] = vrmd.LastModifiedDate ?? Convert.DBNull;
                        if (vrmd.LastModifiedBy == null)
                        {
                            workrow["LastModifiedBy"] = Convert.DBNull;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            workrow["LastModifiedBy"] = vrmd.LastModifiedBy.Name;
                        }
                        lock (CustomTabs)
                        {
                            CustomTabs.Rows.Add(workrow);
                        }

                    });
                    OrgTables.SendDTtoDB(ref CustomTabs, ref _cnn, "OrgCustomTabs");
```

Comment: Can you show us the parallel.for?  Guid.NewGuid should not be producing duplicates; it's likely something you're doing, but we can't inspect that code.

Comment: Updated with the code with the parallel.for loop.

Comment: 9 times out of 10 if you are using `Parallel.For` for a database, you are doing something wrong to start with. Firstly, IO workloads are not suited for those TPL methods. Secondly, Database access is inherently not thread safe. Thirdly, this most likely should be done in a single batch query

Comment: It's done in a loop because I have to query the API over and over to get each item in the object.  I'm doing the Parallel.For loop so I can speed up the process.  If I need to get 450 items or more one at a time, I'd like to multithread that for speed purposes.  The database access isn't being done in the loop, just building the datatable is because once I get the data back from the API I need to store it.

Comment: I notice you are creating the `DataRow` (`DataRow workrow = CustomTabs.NewRow();`) outside of the `lock`, yet according to [Parallel.ForEach and DataTable - Isn't DataTable.NewRow() a thread safe “read” operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56224441/150605) `NewRow()` is not thread-safe.  So perhaps you're not actually creating the same `Guid` twice but a single `Guid` value is getting assigned to multiple rows.

Comment: If you want to speed up bulk inserting, what you want to do is abandon `DataTable` altogether. It is by far the least efficient way to get data to `SqlBulkCopy`. `SqlBulkCopy` is a streaming interface anyway, so gathering data in parallel gains you exactly nothing unless producing the data itself really is the bottleneck. Look at streaming through the overload that takes an `IDataReader`. Do not fetch the source rows one by one in parallel, use an `IN` or a table-valued parameter.

Comment: "so that SQL will generate the id" : you could use SqlBulkCopyColumnMapping to map the source to target. Target columns not mapped will get their defaults https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopycolumnmapping

Comment: Please note, if the guid is generated in the database, you could still get corrupt data in your DataTable when using multiple threads and improper usage of locks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that having to use a `lock` inside the `Parallel.ForEach` in a DataTable,  sort of defeats the purpose of using the `Parallel.ForEach` in the first place; however, I am surprised that you don't get exceptions when you call `DataRow workrow = CustomTabs.NewRow();` because on my test, I get an index corrupted exception. I had to actually wrap the call to `NewRow` inside a lock. Something like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(data, x =>
            {
                DataRow row = null;
                lock (lockRow)
                {
                    row = dt.NewRow();
                    row["Guid"] = Guid.NewGuid();
                }
...
                lock(lockObj)
                   dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

Where `lockObj` and `lockRow` are 2 separate static objects instantiated as

```
static  object lockObj = new  object();
static  object lockRow = new object();
```

And that worked for me, adding 1 million rows to the `DataTable` and making sure that all the Guids were unique.

With all the above said, I would strongly recommend writing the code as suggested by Julian or create a class that implements `IDataReader` (which you can use with SQLBulkCopy) and upload the data using that.

Comment: Nice that you've got it working! I agree with "lock inside the Parallel.ForEach in a DataTable, sort of defeats the purpose of using the Parallel.ForEach". Therefore I proposed and thread safe way without locks. (well of course the concurrent collections aren't guaranteed lock free, but those are lock minimized)

Comment: This is exactly what was happening!  After posting this I found this article [link](https://programmersunlimited.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/datatables-thread-safe/) and figured this part out.  I've made that change and it seems to have resolved the problem.  While ultimately Julian's answer may be the best in the long run, I'm not that skilled yet and looking at the docs, it's greek to me.  I never stop digging and learning so I will figure it out but this gets me back up and running for now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I have seen this issue before. There is no problem with the `Guid.NewGuid()`,  but the `DataTable` isn't threadsafe!

> DataTable is simply not designed or intended for concurrent usage (in particular where there is any form of mutation involved).

See [Thread safety for DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310757/thread-safety-for-datatable#21328343)

Also related:  [c# DataGridView DataTable internal index corrupted in parallel loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51812491/c-sharp-datagridview-datatable-internal-index-corrupted-in-parallel-loop)

> It's done in a loop because I have to query the API over and over to get each item in the object. I'm doing the Parallel.For loop so I can speed up the process. If I need to get 450 items or more one at a time, I'd like to multithread that for speed purposes. The database access isn't being done in the loop, just building the datatable is because once I get the data back from the API I need to store it.

You could create a type and add them multithreaded to a `ConcurrentBag<T>` or `ConcurrentQueue<T>` (or another concurrent collection, see [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent)) - those are thread-safe :)

Then after it you could build the `DataTable` with a single thread. Or maybe skip the whole DataTable if possible for your use case.

Comment: From what I've read, as long as you use a lock when adding the row to the datatable, you should be fine.  Is that not correct?

Comment: I guess you need a lock on the whole table then. But I never try to recommend locks when there are thread-safe alternatives.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and knowledge!  I'm off to Youtube and Google to learn about ConcurrentBag's. :)  I never give up so I'll figure them out eventually!

Answer (score -1):

I used a guidgenerator that I lock every time I access it.

```
lock (guidGenerator)
{
  entity.Id = guidGenerator.NewGuid();
}
```

worked fine for me. It's a different approach though.